# Failing ant.junit in gradle build

Tags: ant, gradle

I'm writing a Gradle task that delegates to `ant.junit`. (Yes, this is what I want to do).

I can't get the build to fail when the tests fail.

```
// this will fail
task breakit << {
    ant.property(name: "broken", value: "!")
    ant.fail(if: 'broken')
}

// this doesn't fail, even though running JUnit against java.lang.String fails.
task breakit << {
    ant.junit(failureproperty: 'broken') { test(name: 'java.lang.String') }
    ant.fail(if: 'broken')
}
```

The behaviour should be the same in both calls to `ant.fail`. The property `broken` should be set, but in the second version it isn't. The build responds with:

```
:breakit                
[ant:junit] TEST java.lang.String FAILED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Using `haltonfailure: 'yes'` doesn't work either - the build is still successful.

How can I fail the build on broken tests?

Comment: Perhaps try `println ant.properties['broken']`. If that's not being set, I don't know what can be done.

Comment: It wasn't being set. In the end I slurped all test report files and threw a GradleException if i found any failures.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of gradle are you using? With version 2.2.1,

```
ant.junit(printsummary: 'on', showoutput: 'yes', haltonfailure: 'no', failureproperty: 'failed', errorproperty: 'errored') {
}

ant.fail(if: 'failed')
ant.fail(if: 'errored')
```

does work for me. You can even confirm that by trying this simple code:

```
ant.failed = 'true'
ant.fail(if: 'failed')
```